# nextval must be declared

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

I created a sequence as the below in oracle 12c with no problem,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;
```

however, I get error which says `"Error(2,25): PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEE_SEQ.NEXTVAL' must be declared"` for the codes below

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_TRG BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE REFERENCING 
    NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        :new.EMPLOYEE_ID := EMPLOYEE_SEQ.nextval;
    END EMPLOYEE_TRG;
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: These are both in the same schema?

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that trigger, you could try:

```
alter table employee add employee_id number default employee_seq.nextval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is not created for that is and error you should try create it again or try something else

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER;
```

this will run but nocache

And try this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER"EMPLOYEE_TRG" 
        BEFORE INSERT ON employee
        FOR EACH ROW
          WHEN (NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL) BEGIN 
        :NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID:=EMPLOYEEE_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
        END;
```

Or check permissions if that doesn't work

Comment: Read about [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also there's no value in answering so old question which are someone's need to fix an error just now.

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been fixed after I granted user of the database

Comment: Granted what to who?

Comment: That would be "grant select on sequence_name to { user | role };